# Can I do a `select * from tbl where id in (<string from another query>)

Tags: mysql, select

Say I want to perform the following query in mysql:

```
select id from tbl where id in (2,3)
```

but the string '2,3' is already stored in another table's column, say `tbl2.data`. Is it possible to do something similar to the following:

```
select id from tbl where id in (select data from tbl2 where x=y);
```

When I tried it, the result was equal to

```
select id from tbl where id in (2);
```

as if the result was converted to the first number

Comment: Your data model is wrong. You shouldn't be storing comma-separated values in the first place.

Comment: you are correct, nevertheless this is what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
    (select group_concat(data) from tbl2 where x=y);
```

or simple use this .

```
   select id from tbl 
   INNER JOIN tbl2
   ON tbl.id = tbl2.data
   WHERE x=Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery, but you need to use `find_in_set()` rather than `in`:

```
select id
from tbl
where exists (select 1 from tbl2 where x=y and find_in_set(id, data) > 0);
```